# unknown recursive method, must find how it runs

Tags: recursion, recurrence

This was a past exam question and I have no idea what it does! Please can someone run through it.

```
public static int befuddle(int n){
      if(n <= 1){
          return n;
      }else{
          return befuddle(n - 1) * befuddle(n - 2) + 1;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

this is computing the sequence: `0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 7, 22, 155, ...`
Which can be expressed using this formula:

[image: formula]

when dealing with numerical sequences, a great resources is [The Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences!](https://oeis.org/), a quick search there shows a similar sequence to yours ***but with***:

[image: formula -2]

giving the following sequence: `0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 7, 22, 155, ...`

you can find more about it [here](https://oeis.org/A007660)

Answer (score 1):

`public static` is the type of member function it is.  I'm assuming this is part of a class?  The static keyword allows you to use it without creating an instance of the class.

Plug in a value of 'n' and step through it. For instance, if n = 1, then the function returns 1.  If n = 0 -> 0; n = -100 -> -100.

If n = 2, the else branch is triggered and befuddled is called with 1 and 0.  So n = 2 returns 0*1 + 1 = 1.

Do the same thing for n = 3, etc.  (calls n = 2 -> 1, and n = 1 -> 1, so n=3 -> 1*1+1 = 2.)

Comment: so for every value will it be